# Using a drop down value to conditionally format the background of another cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to conditionally format a cell in A1 based on the selected value of a drop-down in B1. The values in the drop-down ["Unpaid", "Pending", "Posted"]. I would like the background of cell A1 to change according to the value of B2. White for "Unpaid, Yellow for "Pending", and Green for "Posted". I know this can be accomplished using conditional formatting. I just don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 3 rules in CF.

```
=$B$1="Unpaid"
=$B$1="Pending"
=$B$1="Posted"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are exactly right, and I am sorry, but I had a flash of insight and figured it out almost right after posting my question. Thank you for your answer Harun24hr, I really do appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Do not post this as answer. Rather you can comment to my answer.